# Pandas Udf in Pyspark running in only 1 Executor in yarn client or cluster mode

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a code which reads data from Hive Table and applies a pandas udf, the moment it reads data from table it runs in 11 executors , however the moment it executes a pandas udf it uses only 1 executor. Is there a way to assign say 10 executors to execute pandas udf

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false --conf spark.executor.instances=20 code_test.py


Code Snippet:

    from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("yarn").appName("Test").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    @pandas_udf("double", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
    def mean_udf(v):
        return v.mean()
    df = spark.sql("select id, cast(tran_am as double) as v from table")
    df.groupby("id").agg(mean_udf(df['v'])).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

may need to extract your UDF function to another file, then can broadcast to all executors.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).